# How can I use Make to build NASM-syntax assembly? (Windows)

Tags: assembly, makefile, nasm

Really new to this and I'm kind of clueless and new to doing anything in assembly. Like the title says, im using NASM as the assembler and using Make to build the project.

every resource I've seen online does this on a linux host
If you need me to provide more clarification ill try my best to do so, sorry if this is a stupid question.

Thanks ! <3

Comment: What make implementation and linker do you use with nasm?

Comment: Yes, `nasm -f win64` can make Windows object files, and you can link those into an executable.  For it to do anything useful, the asm source needs to be written to use Windows calling conventions and functions and so on, not Linux system calls.  `make` is just a program for running other programs according to file time-stamp and existence, so it can of course run `nasm` and a linker.